# What algorithm value do I use when -keyalg option is not specified in Java 1.6 keytool?

Tags: java, window, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to use keytool in a window environment but I'm getting an error that says the -keyalg option is mandatory, the guide I'm looking at doesn't have a part that specifies keyalg, so I don't know which algorithm to specify.
I want to know what algorithm value goes into when I didn't give the -keyalg value in java 1.6 version.

I think in java1.6, DSA is used as the default, so I gave the -keyalg value to DSA and created a keystore

Comment: Hello there, can you please share full error message~

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.